# Multpart request is working fine via Junit , but failing with IE browser

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration in my project. I am trying to hit a multipart webservice. I am using `int-http:outbound-gateway` to execute the webservice. I could able to execute the rest service without any issue via Junit, but weirdly the same service is failing when I try to execute using the IE browser. 
The following is the error I am getting:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap] and content type [text/xml;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:481)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:460)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:409)
    at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:372)
```

What could be the reason? Please let me know if you need additional information.

```
<int:chain input-channel="Test-Rest-Channel"  >

        <int:header-filter  header-names="accept-encoding"/>    

         <int:service-activator  ref="httpOutboundGatewayHandler" method="buildMultipartHttpOutboundGatewayRequest" /> 

        <int-http:outbound-gateway  url-expression="headers.restResourceUrl"
                                    http-method-expression="headers.httpMethod"
                                    extract-request-payload="true"
                                    expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>

        <int:transformer expression="'&lt;response>' + payload + '&lt;/response>'"/>
        <int:service-activator ref="msgHandler" method="enrichPayloadXml" />

    </int:chain>
```

I am getting the error `org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String` when I change the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

The complete stack trace is below:

```
2016-12-13 12:50:56,311 DEBUG http-0.0.0.0-8080-5 [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] setting headerName=[Content-Type], value=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
2016-12-13 12:50:56,311 DEBUG http-0.0.0.0-8080-5 [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper] headerName=[originalPayload] WILL NOT be mapped
2016-12-13 12:50:56,311 DEBUG http-0.0.0.0-8080-5 [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Created POST request for "http://10.193.244.136/awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/"
2016-12-13 12:50:56,311 DEBUG http-0.0.0.0-8080-5 [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2016-12-13 12:50:56,311 DEBUG http-0.0.0.0-8080-5 [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate] Writing [{source=[file [C:\Users\dt212693\AppData\Local\Temp\temp2340685368206282153443984647956344\source.xml]], attachment=[file [C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg]]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" using [org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter@660c43f2]
2016-12-13 12:50:56,311 WARN  http-0.0.0.0-8080-5 [org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway] failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI [http://10.193.244.136/awdServer/awd/services/v1/instances/]
                at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:398)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:142)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:256)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$ReplyForwardingMessageChannel.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:249)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:167)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:134)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:148)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:131)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.router.AbstractMessageRouter.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMessageRouter.java:150)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:169)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:228)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:212)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:177)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:171)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:149)
                at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
                at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
                at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:330)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:361)
                at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
                at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:234)
                at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:208)
                at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.actualDoHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:478)
                at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.doHandleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:380)
                at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:101)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
                at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
                at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeForm(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:232)
                at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:196)
                at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:72)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:656)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:481)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:460)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:409)
                at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:372)
                ... 138 more
```

When I used `Content-Type` header as `multipart/form-data` , I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden
                at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:532)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:488)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:460)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:409)
                at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:372)
                ... 138 more
```

**EDIT** The header `Content-Type` as `multipart/form-data` working fine with the JUNIT.

When I used `Accept` header as `multipart/form-data` , I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap] and content type [text/xml;charset=UTF-8]
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:665)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:481)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:460)
                at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:409)
                at org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:372)
                ... 138 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.HashMap] and content type [text/xml;charset=UTF-8]

I think your JUnit test manipulates with a bit different payload type. But here you have `Map` payload which really can't be converted to the `text/xml`.

Or provide some transformer to convert map to an appropriate for XML conversion type, or change the `content-type` header to let that map be serialized as a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

**UPDATE**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String
            at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.writeForm(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:232)
            at org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter.write(FormHttpMessageConverter.java:196)
```

Looks like you `Map` contains some values which are `FileSystemResource` but not plain `String`. And from other side you don't pass `isMultipart` condition and I guess because you have wrong `contentType`:

```
private boolean isMultipart(MultiValueMap<String, ?> map, MediaType contentType) {
    if (contentType != null) {
        return MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.includes(contentType);
    }
```

Not sure if `multipart/form-data` as a `contentType`, but you really should be sure that you expect to send multipart, not plain form.

Just really to to use :

```
 msgBuild.setHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting the error `org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String` when I change the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Can you share more StackTrace on the matter? As an edit for your question would be the best choice to go ahead

Comment: Once again thanks for your support. I have added the added the complete stack trace to the question.

Comment: I have created a new Question for the current issue so that it would be easily accessible to the people whoever faces similar issue in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143430/classcastexception-is-thrown-for-a-multipart-request-when-it-is-sent-via-http-ou

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer. Sorry, for delay. Will take a look into your other question later.

Comment: The `Map` contains two files. one is `xml` and the other one can be anything like `txt,jpg, gif` etc. I have experimented by placing `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, but no use. I didn't understand the necessity of `isMultipart` condition when I can explicitly define the `Content-Type` it self. Could you please elaborate and share your ideas on how to fix the issue?

Comment: One more update is that when I use `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the JUNIT is also failing by throwing `FileSystemResource cannot be cast to String`.

Comment: Ok. What's the problem do you have when you use `multiparty/form-data`?

Comment: I have added the details to the question it self. I mean using `Content-Type` header as `multipart/form-data`. I even experimented with `Accept` header too. You can find more details in the question now. Please take a look. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: `403 Forbidden` means that you have reached REST service already, but looks like it doesn't like your request. Please, consult with your service provider to determine what else you have to add or remove to meet their requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The weird part is that it's working fine with JUNIT. I will contact the service provider to know what's going wrong here. Thanks for your continuous support.